# how to show Screen within MainScreen in application

Tags: blackberry, screen, fieldmanager, mainscreen

My application have one screen below the detail of that. Screen name **EventList** . This screen have designed full. There are two `ButtonField` `Next` and `Previous` . At the bottom of these two `Button` `ListField` is placed in this screen.

When i click on `Next` or `Previous` my `ListField` will update . It is updated successfully using `updateListField() method` which is created in this screen. All is working fine up to this. But my concern is that when i click on these `Button` `ListField` will take time (around 3 or 4 second)to update new data. During my data updating in background i want to show `Massage` like `Please wait.../Loading...`. How can i show this without using `PopupScreen`.

i had tried the below code but not working properly.

```
VerticalFieldManager manager = new VerticalFieldManager();

manager.add(new LabelField("Please Wait..."));
Screen popup = new PopupScreen(manager);
```

If i will done this using `PopupScreen` my full logic will be change for that screen and it will time consuming task.

Please suggest me how can we add `FieldManager` on existing `MainScreen`.

Thanks in Advance !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Application.getApplication().invokeLater( 
new Runnable() { 
public void run() { 

GIFEncodedImage image; 
EncodedImage encodedImage = EncodedImage 
.getEncodedImageResource("spiral.gif"); 
byte data[] = new byte[3000]; 
data = encodedImage.getData(); 
image = (GIFEncodedImage) EncodedImage 
.createEncodedImage( 
data, 0, 
data.length); 
AnimatedGIFField animatedGIF = new AnimatedGIFField( 
image); 

PopupScreen popup = new PopupScreen( 
new VerticalFieldManager()); 
popup.add(animatedGIF); 
Border border = BorderFactory 
.createSimpleBorder( 
new XYEdges(), 
Border.STYLE_SOLID); 
popup.setBorder(border); 
UiApplication 
.getUiApplication() 
.pushScreen(popup); 

Timer timer = new Timer(); 
timer.schedule(new CountDown(), 
3000); 

} 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The MainScreen class includes a status field that you can use for this. In your class extending MainScreen add:

```
setStatus(new LabelField("Please wait..."));
```

to remove that status:

```
setStatus(null);
```

However, you need to do this on the event thread and then return so the OS can update the user interface. If you are performing the update of your list on the event thread (the thread that will call your code when the button is pressed) then you should perform that work on a spearate thread and use UiApplication.invokeLater() or hold the event lock to perform updates on the user interface.